# add custom date on video with ffmpeg android

Tags: java, linux, ffmpeg

I used this command for current time "drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/Roboto-Regular.ttf:fontcolor=white:text='%{localtime}':x=0:y=h/2-ascent"
but it shows encoded time start from current
And i want video duration from custom date time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved 
"drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/Roboto-Regular.ttf:fontcolor=white:text='%{pts \: gmtime}':x=0:y=h/2-ascent"